# Why my sub url can not be accessed directly after a deploy my react project on server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I built a react project. The react version is 17.0.2 and the react-router-dom version is 6.2.1. I used "npm run build" and deployed the build folder to the server. The site can be visited and the site can jump to any specific page when I click the link button on the homepage or any other pages. But except homepage, when I refresh the page or I use the URL to visit this page, it will show "not found". This situation doesn't appear on local when I code.
What is causing this problem and how to address it?
Thanks!
The following is part of my code on index.js and app.js

#### index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### app.js

```
function App() {
 return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <Landingpage />} exact />
        <Route path="/aboutus" element={ <AboutUsPage />} />
        <Route path="/myservice" element={ <MyServicePage />} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" element={ <PortfolioPage />} exact />
        <Route path="/portfolio/:projectId" element={ <ProjectPage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={ <ContactPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: `What is causing this problem and how to address it?` This happens when the server distributing your React App doesn't redirect unmatched urls to your main route (`/` by default) so React-router can handle the URL. In express, you'd do something like `app('/*', express.serve('/public/'))` - mind the wildcard here. The problem here is not react but the server serving your React app

Comment: The server needs to redirect the requested "nested routes" to the directory your app is being served from. How this is done depends on the server, i.e. where your app is deployed. Different servers handle this similarly, but with different implementations/scripting/configurations/etc... Where are you deploying the app?

Comment: @DrewReese I deploying on google server （Debian）